# How to enable code hinting for the user defined functions in SublimeText?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

How to enable code hinting for the user defined functions in SublimeText?

e.g. if I declare a function in my project like this:

```
function my_func($arg1,$arg2){
// some code
}
```

and then I type 'my_func' in some other file, then it gives me hint and auto-completes the code for me, as it does for the default php functions like substr() etc.

Is there a way in SublimeText for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question? I think this is a legitimate question. Found this in a search for the same. Upvoting to help get this out of negative range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime text is a code editor and not an IDE. So don't expect to have IDE features in it. But you can use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPIntel for PHP code completion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel). You'll need to have [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) installed first. The plugin is based on Komodo, and supports code completion (and several other features) for many different languages, including PHP. You'll need to customize the configuration for your individual needs, but the settings are pretty well documented, so it shouldn't be too difficult. If you have any issues, search Stack Overflow as there are a number of answers regarding its configuration.

Good luck!

Comment: I have already tried it. It's good for built-in syntax highlighting but does not help me in my issue. I have to use PHPStorm. But it would be great if SublimeText had this functionality.